# Css won't compile when running angularjs and angular app side by side

Tags: css, angularjs, angular, webpack, angular-cli

I am running into a problem with my css when trying to convert to a hybrid angularjs/angular application using angular-cli.

```
ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!../node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--15-3!./src/styles.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
SyntaxError

(2:4) Unknown word

  1 | //
> 2 | // Copyright 2017 Google Inc.
    |    ^
  3 | //
  4 | // Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
```

I previously used webpack to handle my css/scss:

```
{
    test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
    use: [
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
            sourceMap: true
        }
        },
        {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            includePaths: ['./css', './node_modules']
        }
        },
        {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            plugins: () => [
            postcssCustomProperties({
                importFrom: ['./css/variables.css']
            })
            ]
        }
        }
    ]
}
```

Seems like angular-cli's webpack build does not process css the same way my old angularjs project did.  I would like to keep my angularjs project separated from the new angular project.  How do I build and include all the "old" css from my angularjs project?

Comment: As far as I know, CSS does not have single line comments. You need to check how the file is being used. If it's read straight up as CSS, it won't work. And from the error it seems like it is.

Comment: I noticed that as well. It's strange that the error is being thrown on the line 2 column 4. And the syntax error is for a word. If it didn't like the comments, I would expect and error on line 1 column 1. I assume it's a scss file and not a css

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you have some css files from your angularjs project that you want to add to your angular project. It's not clear if you want them bundled up with the application or if you're just trying to make two projects fit into a single dist folder.

If you're wanting to include your angularjs css files in angular, you have a couple of options:

**angular.json > styles**
Add the styles directly into your `angular.json` file.

```
"styles": [
  "/some/styles/cssfile.css"
],
```

**Use assets directory**
You can always throw whatever you want into the `assets` directory and it will get bundled up as-is. Make sure your `angular.json` is bundling your assets directory (I can't remember if this is the default).

```
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/assets"
],
```

**Other options**

- Add your file references to the `index.html` file in your new angular app.
- Just import your css files into the main `styles.scss` file in your angular project (`@import 'some/ref'`).

Comment: I am trying to use the styles.scss file that angular-cli made.  Running into problems importing css files @import "./src/ng1/css/angularjs.css".  Seems all files need to be scss, not a mix of scss and css?

Comment: No, they can be a mix. Here's an example: Angular Material wants you to import a `css` file if you want a prebuilt theme (https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme). Also, please upvote/mark as answer if this helps/solves your problem.

Comment: I am confused, you mention they can mix, then you also metion "If your angularjs files are (or can be) scss, just import them into the main styles.scss file in your angular project (@import 'some/ref')"

Answer (score 0):

Can you share angular.json file. If angular.json file is configured properly with `"styles":[ ]` for Angular CLI than you do not need any loaders.  Error indicates you are still using old school webpack.